# Асинхронный сокет С++ (WinSock2.h) vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, http, visual-studio-2010, сокеты

Делаю HTTP сервер, точнее класс чтобы всегда был высокоуровневый инструмент для этой задачи. Но он блокирует роботу программы ожидая запроса. Как сделать так чтобы он не блокировал ход выполнения цыкала.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <stdlib.h>



    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501

    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>

    // Необходимо, чтобы линковка происходила с DLL-библиотекой
    // Для работы с сокетам
    #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

    using std::cerr;


        const int max_client_buffer_size = 1024;
        char buf[max_client_buffer_size];
        int client_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    class HTTPserver
    {
    public:
        bool error;

         WSADATA wsaData; // служебная структура для хранение информации
        // о реализации Windows Sockets
        // старт использования библиотеки сокетов процессом
        // (подгружается Ws2_32.dll)
        int result;// = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);



        struct addrinfo* addr;// = NULL; // структура, хранящая информацию
        // об IP-адресе  слущающего сокета


         // Шаблон для инициализации структуры адреса
            struct addrinfo hints;


             int listen_socket;

        HTTPserver(char* ip,char *port)
        {
            error = false;
            result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

            // Если произошла ошибка подгрузки библиотеки
            if (result != 0) {
                cerr << "WSAStartup failed: " << result << "\n";
                //return result;
                error = true;
                return;
            }

            addr = NULL; // структура, хранящая информацию

             // Шаблон для инициализации структуры адреса
            //struct addrinfo hints;
            ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));

            hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // AF_INET определяет, что будет
            // использоваться сеть для работы с сокетом
            hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Задаем потоковый тип сокета
            hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP; // Используем протокол TCP
            hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // Сокет будет биндиться на адрес,
            // чтобы принимать входящие соединения

            // Инициализируем структуру, хранящую адрес сокета - addr
            // Наш HTTP-сервер будет висеть на 8000-м порту локалхоста
            result = getaddrinfo(ip, port, &hints, &addr);

            // Если инициализация структуры адреса завершилась с ошибкой,
            // выведем сообщением об этом и завершим выполнение программы
            if (result != 0) {
                cerr << "getaddrinfo failed: " << result << "\n";
                WSACleanup(); // выгрузка библиотеки Ws2_32.dll
                //return 1;
                error = false;
                return;
            }













        // Создание сокета
        listen_socket = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype,
            addr->ai_protocol);
        // Если создание сокета завершилось с ошибкой, выводим сообщение,
        // освобождаем память, выделенную под структуру addr,
        // выгружаем dll-библиотеку и закрываем программу
        if (listen_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            cerr << "Error at socket: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            freeaddrinfo(addr);
            WSACleanup();
            //return 1;
            error = false;
            return;
        }



        // Привязываем сокет к IP-адресу
        result = bind(listen_socket, addr->ai_addr, (int)addr->ai_addrlen);

        // Если привязать адрес к сокету не удалось, то выводим сообщение
        // об ошибке, освобождаем память, выделенную под структуру addr.
        // и закрываем открытый сокет.
        // Выгружаем DLL-библиотеку из памяти и закрываем программу.
        if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cerr << "bind failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            freeaddrinfo(addr);
            closesocket(listen_socket);
            WSACleanup();
            //return 1;
            error = false;
            return;
        }

        // Инициализируем слушающий сокет
        if (listen(listen_socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cerr << "listen failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            closesocket(listen_socket);
            WSACleanup();
           // return 1;
            error = false;
            return;
        }


        //const int max_client_buffer_size = 1024;
        //char buf[max_client_buffer_size];
        client_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;


        }

        /*void Scan(std::string (*func)(std::string))
        {
            std::string r = "";

            Scan(func, r);
        }*/


        void VerifyR(std::string (*func)(std::string))
        {
               // for (;;)
                {
            // Принимаем входящие соединения
            client_socket = accept(listen_socket, NULL, NULL);
            if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                cerr << "accept failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
                closesocket(listen_socket);
                WSACleanup();
               // return 1;
                error = false;
                return;
            }


            result = recv(client_socket, buf, max_client_buffer_size, 0);

            std::stringstream response; // сюда будет записываться ответ клиенту
            std::stringstream response_body; // тело ответа

            if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                // ошибка получения данных
                cerr << "recv failed: " << result << "\n";
                closesocket(client_socket);
            } else if (result == 0) {
                // соединение закрыто клиентом
                cerr << "connection closed...\n";
             } else if (result > 0) {
                // Мы знаем фактический размер полученных данных, поэтому ставим метку конца строки
                // В буфере запроса.
                buf[result] = '\0';



                 // Формируем весь ответ вместе с заголовками
                response << func(buf);



                // Отправляем ответ клиенту с помощью функции send
                result = send(client_socket, response.str().c_str(),
                    response.str().length(), 0);



                if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    // произошла ошибка при отправле данных
                    cerr << "send failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
                }
                // Закрываем соединение к клиентом
                closesocket(client_socket);
            }
        }

        }

        void Verify(std::string (*func)(std::string))
        {

            // Принимаем входящие соединения
            client_socket = accept(listen_socket, NULL, NULL);

            if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {cerr << "accept failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";  closesocket(listen_socket); WSACleanup();  error = false; return; }

            result = recv(client_socket, buf, max_client_buffer_size, 0);

            std::stringstream response; // сюда будет записываться ответ клиенту
            std::stringstream response_body; // тело ответа

            if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) { cerr << "recv failed: " << result << "\n";   closesocket(client_socket);} else if (result == 0) { cerr << "connection closed...\n";} else if (result > 0) 
            {
                // Мы знаем фактический размер полученных данных, поэтому ставим метку конца строки
                // В буфере запроса.
                buf[result] = '\0';

                // Данные успешно получены
                // формируем тело ответа (HTML)
                response_body << func(buf);

                //ByString 

                // Формируем весь ответ вместе с заголовками
                response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                    << "Version: HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                    << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
                    << "Content-Length: " << response_body.str().length()
                    << "\r\n\r\n"
                    << response_body.str();

                // Отправляем ответ клиенту с помощью функции send
                result = send(client_socket, response.str().c_str(), response.str().length(), 0);



                if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    // произошла ошибка при отправле данных
                    cerr << "send failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
                }
                // Закрываем соединение к клиентом
                closesocket(client_socket);
            }


        }

        ~HTTPserver()
        {
              // Убираем за собой
            closesocket(listen_socket);
            freeaddrinfo(addr);
            WSACleanup();
        }

    };

    //Получить один из ІР первый попавшыйся
    std::string GetIP()
    {
    std::string out = "WinSock ERR";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (!WSAStartup(WINSOCK_VERSION, &wsaData)){char chInfo[64];
    if (!gethostname(chInfo, sizeof(chInfo)))
    {
    hostent *sh;
    sh=gethostbyname((char*)&chInfo);
    if (sh!=NULL)
    {
    int nAdapter = 0;
    while (sh->h_addr_list[nAdapter])
    {
    struct sockaddr_in adr;
    memcpy(&adr.sin_addr, sh->h_addr_list[nAdapter], sh->h_length);
    out = inet_ntoa(adr.sin_addr);
    nAdapter++;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    WSACleanup();
    return out;
    }

    //Получить фаил в формате строки
    bool getFile(char* url,std::string &r)
    {
        r = "";
        std::ifstream in(url);
                if(in)
                {
                    while(1)
                    {
                        char t;
                        in.get(t);
                        if(in.eof()) break;
                        r+=t;
                    }
                in.close();
                }
                else
                return false;
                return true;
    }

    std::string reqset(std::string  zapross)
    {
        std::string zp;

        std::ifstream in("index.html");
        if(in)
        {
            while(1)
            {
                char t = in.get();
                if(in.eof()) break;

                zp+=t;
            }
        in.close();
        }
        else
            zp = "Noo File";

        zp+="<p>Zapross send v otvet</p>";
            zapross;
            for(int i = 0; i < zapross.size(); i++)
            {
                if(zapross[i] != '\n')
                zp+= zapross[i];
                else
                {
                    zp+= "<p></p>";
                }
            }

        return zp;
    }

    int main()
    {

        //Присвоить реальную ip из адаптора первого
        std::string sIP = GetIP();
        std::cout<<sIP<<'\n';

        //Установить ip сервера
        HTTPserver F((char*)sIP.c_str(),"80");
        //Если ошыбки всё конец
        if(F.error) return 0;

       while(1)
       {
           //Запустить на ожыдание запросса
           F.Verify(reqset);
          std::cout<<"------\n";
       }










        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Смотреть в сторону функции select() и ее аналогов. Вот пример какой то для winsock нашел https://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancediomethod5a.html

Comment: Обратите внимание, сокет на которомы делается listen так же переводится в неблокирующий режим и так же скармливается select среди прочих

Comment: 1. socket NON BLOCK 2. Используйте Thread

Comment: Уже пробовал в поток отправлять ожидание запроса но что то не сработало. попробую ещё отпишу.